# SQL connection not closed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

How can we close connections that are open by another application? I have application that is not closing application I need to find a way to close inactive connections to server.

Enterprise library is used for database CRUD operations and I need a quick workaround. I can not the application and I have to write a utility that closes connections that are inactive and older than 15 minutes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You an kill connections from the server or something physical like disconnecting from the network. I don't know that there's a way at the application layer to kill connections in other processes.

Comment: OK. How can I diagnose where in code its leaving connections open? Unfortunately, it is happening on production environment and it is not happening on staging.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use something like this

```
DECLARE @seconds int = 600
DECLARE @spid int
DECLARE @sql char(200)

DECLARE spid_cursor SCROLL INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
SELECT s.spid
FROM 
    master..sysprocesses s
WHERE 
    ( datediff( ss, s.last_batch, getdate())) > @seconds
    AND spid > 50 --only target user processes

OPEN spid_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM spid_cursor INTO @spid

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'kill ' + convert(char(4), @spid)
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM spid_cursor INTO @spid
END

DEALLOCATE spid_cursor
GO
```

Comment: This closes the SPID on SQL but TCP connection is left open. It causes The name limit for the local computer network adapter card was exceeded error. Sorry does not work :(